# Node JS handing HTTP redirects manually and preserve cookies

Tags: node.js

I have multiple redirects in my case (not just one redirect, there are 3 redirects happen when I access a URL). I am using request module and found that the redirects not preserving the auth,cookies and other options, also not getting authenticated and always getting 401.

Any example code for the same, will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide more information here for me to accurately answer your question. But as far as my understanding goes, you have one URL, after which you automatically redirect to another URL, and then to another one and so on.

So, assuming you have used ExpressJS, this code works in preserving cookie values

```
router.get('/redirect1', function(req, res, next) {
     res.cookie('name1','Cookie 1 Data');    //Setting First Cookie
     res.redirect('redirect2');
});

router.get('/redirect2', function(req, res, next) {
     var cookie = req.cookies['name1'];
     res.cookie('name2','Cookie 2 Data');   //Setting Second Cookie
     res.redirect('redirect3');
});

router.get('/redirect3', function(req, res, next) {
     var cookie = req.cookies['name1'];  //Fetching cookie1 Value
     var cookie2 = req.cookies['name2'];  //Fetching cookie2 Value
     res.send({name1:cookie,name2:cookie2});
 });
```

Please provide more data/code in order to provide a clearer picture.